# Generating json data and filtering on matching condition from a specific table

Tags: sql, mysql, json, inner-join, aggregate-functions

Table "**ORDER**":

| ID | ORDERN_NUM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 321 |
| 3 | 456 |

Table "**RECEIVERS**":

| FIRST_NAME | ID | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pete | 1 | Tyler |
| Sarah | 1 | Bowden |
| Bart | 2 | Simpson |

Table "**PRODUCTS**":

| TYPE | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Towel | 1 |
| Pen | 1 |
| Spoon | 2 |

We can say "*FIRST_NAME*" and "*TYPE*" are primary keys for their respective tables, but that doesn't matter for this question.  The important part is that "*ORDER*" has primary key "*ID*", and "*ID*" is foreign key in "*PRODUCTS*" and "*RECEIVERS*".

I've tried to develop a single query, which allows the user to query on "*RECEIVERS.FIRST_NAME*". The query would then join on all three tables, and return everything related to "*ID*" = 1.  So if I were to query on "*Pete*", I would be given back an object such as below:

```
[{
    "ID": "1",
    "ORDERN_NUM": "123",
    "RECEIVERS": [{
        "FIRST_NAME": "Pete",
        "LAST_NAME": "Tyler"
    },
    {
        "FIRST_NAME": "Sarah",
        "LAST_NAME": "Bowden"
    }],
    "PRODUCTS": [{
        "TYPE": "Towel"
    },
    {
        "TYPE": "Pen"
    }]
}]
```

I so far have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('ID', o.ID, 'RECEIVERS', r.RECEIVERS, 'PRODUCTS', p.PRODUCTS))
FROM       ORDER AS o
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID,
                   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('firstName', FIRST_NAME, 'lastName', LAST_NAME)) RECEIVERS
            FROM RECEIVERS
            GROUP BY ID) r on o.ID = r.ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID,
                   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('type', TYPE)) PRODUCTS
            FROM PRODUCTS
            GROUP BY ID) p on o.ID = p.ID
WHERE RECEIVERS.FIRST_NAME = "Pete"
```

However when searching on `FIRST_NAME = 'Pete'`, it will indeed bring all "*ORDER*"s back associated with Pete with all "*PRODUCTS*" in a nested array, and Pete's details in a nested array, however it will not bring back Sarah as a "*RECEIVER*".

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `where RECEIVERS.FIRST_NAME = "Pete"` is a syntax error, as `RECEIVERS` is not defined. Probably you meant `where r.FIRST_NAME = "Pete"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, the problem is with the `where` clause of the query; it filters on orders that belong to Tyler, while you seem to want orders that have the same `id` as those that belong to Tyler.

You could simply change this:

```
where r.FIRST_NAME = "Pete"
```

To:

```
where r.id in (select id from receivers where first_name = 'Pete')
```

In your query:

```
select count(*), 
    json_arrayagg(json_object('ID', o.ID, 'RECEIVERS', r.RECEIVERS, 'PRODUCTS', p.PRODUCTS))
from orders as o
inner join (
    select id,
        json_arrayagg(json_object('firstName', FIRST_NAME, 'lastName', LAST_NAME)) RECEIVERS
    FROM receivers
    group by id
) r on o.id = r.id
  inner join (
    select id,
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('type', TYPE)) PRODUCTS
    FROM PRODUCTS
    group by id
) p on o.id = p.id
where r.id in (select id from receivers where first_name = 'Pete')
```

We could also express this logic with another join:

```
select count(*), 
    json_arrayagg(json_object('ID', o.ID, 'RECEIVERS', r.RECEIVERS, 'PRODUCTS', p.PRODUCTS))
from orders as o
inner join (
    select id,
        json_arrayagg(json_object('firstName', FIRST_NAME, 'lastName', LAST_NAME)) RECEIVERS
    FROM receivers
    group by id
) r on o.id = r.id
  inner join (
    select id,
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('type', TYPE)) PRODUCTS
    FROM PRODUCTS
    group by id
) p on o.id = p.id
inner join receivers as r1 on r1.id = o.id
where r1.first_name = 'Pete'
```

Comment: Thank you, I went with your first solution as I was getting an error on the last line of the second solution `where o1.first_name = 'Pete'` -> no column named o1.first_name.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with an `EXISTS` expression right after the join operations, where you check on matching ids and matching first_name.

```
...
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM receivers rec 
             WHERE rec.ID = o.ID 
               AND rec.FIRST_NAME = 'Pete')
```

Here's the full query:

```
WITH receivers_agg AS(
    SELECT ID, 
           JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                JSON_OBJECT('FIRST_NAME', FIRST_NAME, 
                             'LAST_NAME',  LAST_NAME)
           ) AS list_receivers
    FROM receivers
    GROUP BY ID
), products_agg AS(
    SELECT ID, 
           JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                JSON_OBJECT('TYPE', TYPE)
           ) AS list_products
    FROM products
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(        'ID',         o.ID,
                   'ORDERN_NUM', o.ORDERN_NUM,
                    'RECEIVERS', r.list_receivers,
                     'PRODUCTS', p.list_products  ) AS jsondata
FROM       orders        o
INNER JOIN receivers_agg r ON o.ID = r.ID
INNER JOIN products_agg  p ON o.ID = p.ID
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM receivers rec 
             WHERE rec.ID = o.ID 
               AND rec.FIRST_NAME = 'Pete')
```

Check the full demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rTgQHgXXtHy9qLPB8ypFA9/0).

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to answer the question.  I can see this works nicely, however I am writing this using the pypika package in python and have found @GMB's solution to be a touch easier to code.

Comment: Usually this solution gets faster when the list gets bigger `name IN (a, b, c, d, e,...)`, but since you're matching for one value only (id=1 for Pete), Gmb's solution should be just fine.